# Install packages on PostgreSQL RDS AWS

Tags: postgresql, ldap, amazon-rds, postgres-fdw

I want to access LDAP data from postgreSQL query. I can use FDW (foreign data wrapper) package (https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers#LDAP_Wrappers) but it seems like not supported with RDS yet. Is there any other way I can enable query from postgres to LDAP?

Thanks,
Himanshu

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.FeatureSupport.Extensions

LDAP Wrappers are not supported atm, only:

- log_fdw
- postgres_fdw